# Pointer to struct object as parameter to function - Weird text showing up when printing

Tags: c++, class, pointers, struct

I have a class, that contains a struct. I have a method on the class that creates a new object of this struct, return it as a pointer.

I have another method in this class that takes a pointer to this struct and prints out it's data.

Only problem is, some weird text shows up in the console when I try to print it out.

Code example (not actual code, but the principle of it):

```
// Header

class TestClass
{
    public:

        struct TestStruct
        {
            int ID;
            string Name;
        };

        TestClass::TestStruct* CreateStruct(string name, int id);
        void PrintStruct(TestClass:TestStruct* testStruct);
}

// C++ File

TestClass::TestStruct* TestClass::CreateStruct(string name, int id)
{

    TestStruct testStruct;

    testStruct.ID = id;
    testStruct.Name = name;

    TestClass::TestStruct *pStruct = &testStruct;

    return pStruct;

};

void TestClass::PrintStruct(TestClass::TestStruct* testStruct)
{

    cout << (testStruct)->ID << "\n";
    cout << (testStruct)->Name << "\n";

};

int Main()
{

    TestClass tClass;

    tClass.PrintStruct(tClass.CreateStruct("A name", 1));

}
```

Comment: Also a beep is heard, then some weird text.

Comment: Beeps are actually being produced by weird symbols, but this doesn't matter as undefined buhaviour is very undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're returning a pointer to a local variable, and running into **undefined behavior**.

```
TestClass::TestStruct* TestClass::CreateStruct(string name, int id)
{
    TestStruct testStruct;
    //...
    TestClass::TestStruct *pStruct = &testStruct;
    return pStruct;
}   //testStruct is destroyed here
    //the pointer pStruct is invalid
```

To get this to work, you can either return a smart pointer or allocate the memory dynamically to extend the lifetime of the object. Remember that you have to `delete` it explicitly:

```
TestClass::TestStruct* TestClass::CreateStruct(string name, int id)
{

    TestStruct* testStruct = new TestStruct;

    testStruct->ID = id;
    testStruct->Name = name;

    return testStruct;

};
```

Also, seriously think about whether you actually need pointers. Prefer automatic variables when possible. If I were you, I'd do:

```
TestClass::TestStruct TestClass::CreateStruct(string name, int id)
{

    TestStruct testStruct;
    testStruct.ID = id;
    testStruct.Name = name;
    return testStruct;
};

void TestClass::PrintStruct(const TestClass::TestStruct& testStruct) const
{
    cout << testStruct.ID << "\n";
    cout << testStruct.Name << "\n";
};
```

Comment: The second example worked, I just figured it out earlier that it probably had something to do with the object not existing anymore. How do I later delete it explicitly?

Comment: @Deukalion just `delete` the pointer that gets returned when you no longer need it.